# Fallo en hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, intellij-idea

Al implementar el hibernate.cfg.xml en el IDE Intellij IDEA, me están dando error en las property name.
Aparte de ejecutar Hibernate, tengo incluido Spring Boot, JPA Persistence y ORM. Cómo lo soluciono, por favor?

Muchas gracias.

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://xxxxxx/xxxxxx</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <mapping resource="ejemplo.hbm.xml" />
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo tendré en cuenta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado solución, no era necesario este archivo, ya que Spring Boot lo genera por defecto. Muchas gracias y disculpad las molestias causadas.